# xml validity, ajax, and php

Tags: php, xml, ajax

I'm returning some XML from PHP to Javascript via ajax and getting some 'invalid xml' errors. The xml I'm returning looks like this:

> `<response>
>
>           <song>tdb2009-01-29s2s06</song>
>
>           <song>tdb2009-01-29s1s02</song>
>
>         </response>`

And my javascript to parse it looks like:

```
 function u_handleServerResponse(){  
   //pull xml from xml response  
   var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;

   //check to see if xml was pulled
   if(!xmlResponse || !xmlResponse.documentElement){
     throw("Invalid XML Structure:\n" + xmlHttp.responseText);
   }

   //this is for catching errors with firefox
   var rootNodeName = xmlResponse.documentElement.nodeName;

   //check for errors
   if(rootNodeName == "parsererror"){
     throw("Invalid XML Strucutre");
   }

   //get the root
   xmlRoot = xmlResponse.documentElement;

   var songArray = xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName("song");

  for(var i = 0; i < songArray.length; i++){   
   etc., etc...
```

And I'm getting a

> Error reading the response: Invalid XML Strucutre

error. Does all this look right to you? Is the xml wrong or is it being loaded wrong? All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If you still have problems take a look at this article: 
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6141415.html

Regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include an xml header...

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Comment: Do you know how I could do that in PHP (where I'm building the xml)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the XML header pointed out by rikh, you may need to declare the Content-Type header as text/xml for the responseXML to be correctly populated.

Comment: I do that @ the begining of the php file which creates and returns the xml. Do I need to do it elsewhere?

<?php

//turn on error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
etc...